# wxPython drawing Ellipse arc and anti aliasing

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I just started using wxPython and for my project I need to use wx. Here is the question I drawing a ellipse arc using *wx.PaintDC* is there a way to smooth drawings(anti aliasing)? I found that *wx.GraphicContext* have a anti aliasing but there is not way to draw ellipse arc is there?

Thank you.

```
    dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
    dc.Clear()
    dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('#000000', wx.TRANSPARENT))
    dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.BLACK, 4))

    dc.DrawEllipticArc(10, 10, 100, 100, 270, 0)
```

Comment: can you show some code on how you are drawing? Also, did you try the demo that you can grab from the wxPython web site?

Comment: Igor post is updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do need to use `wxGraphicsContext` for AA support and it does support drawing arcs, of course, you just need to use [wxGraphicsPath::AddArcToPoint()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_graphics_path.html#acb1c90212eb13f75d7a73a1444cbd852) directly instead of relying on (non-existent) `DrawArc()` helper in `wxGraphicsContext` itself.